# An error occured while installing charlock_holmes libicu

Tags: redhat, rhel, gitlab, bundle-install

I'm trying to install Gitlab following [this install script](https://github.com/mattias-ohlsson/gitlab-installer/blob/master/gitlab-install-el6.sh), but am running into an issue where the **charlock_holmes** gem fails to install. I'm not familiar with Ruby. My charlock_holmes-0.6.8 `gem_make.out` file is below.

```
/home/gitlabuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -licui18n... no
which: no brew in (/home/gitlabuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/gitlabuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/home/gitlabuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/gitlabuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/gitlabuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/home/gitlabuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/gitlabuser/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/gitlabuser/bin:/usr/lib64/qt4/bin/)
checking for main() in -licui18n... no


***************************************************************************************
*********** icu required (brew install icu4c or apt-get install libicu-dev) ***********
***************************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/gitlabuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
    --with-icu-dir
    --without-icu-dir
    --with-icu-include
    --without-icu-include=${icu-dir}/include
    --with-icu-lib
    --without-icu-lib=${icu-dir}/lib
    --with-icui18nlib
    --without-icui18nlib
    --with-icui18nlib
    --without-icui18nlib
```

I have the **libicu.x86_64** package installed (and also tried the **libicu.i686** when I ran into problems, but uninstalled it after it didn't work).

It appears the **libicu** package isn't including the files required by the **charlock_holmes** gem, but there aren't any *devel* packages available. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same Problem here. Installed libicu-devel-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64.rpm from red hat and the install of charlock_holmes succeeded.
From https://rhn.redhat.com/rhn/software/packages/details/Overview.do?pid=680099
You will need a Red Hat Network login to get it though.
Note I read says it is part of the "optional" packages.

Comment: I created a personal account and clicked the link you provided while logged in and get a `We're sorry, but the package could not be found.` message, but I found it at http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/centos-rhel-x86_64/libicu-devel-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64.rpm/download/

Answer (score 9):

RedHat, CentOS, Fedora:

`yum install libicu-devel`

Debian, Ubuntu, Mint:

`apt-get install libicu-dev`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem (using CentOS 6, which is identical to RedHat EL 6). I used "yum install libicu-devel", which installed libicu-devel-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2.x86_64.rpm and ultimately allowed charlock_holmes to be installed

Answer (score 0):

Using yum install libicu-devel worked for me, then I could install charlock_holmes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem when deploying to heroku, my solution was to invert the buildpacks:

First:

```
    https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
```

Then:

```
    heroku/ruby
```

Hope I helped!
François